# Virtual machine work on only one system?

Tags: virtualbox, security, virtual-machine, vmware

How can I make a virtual machine to run only on one system(Virtual box or Vmware)?
Is there any way to make it system hardware dependent?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have some problems with moving VM to other systems? VM hardware is completely virtual, host's hardware shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think he wants to stop that from happening

Comment: Please explain why you would want to lock a VM to a certain HW. There might be other ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible nor is it a feature of any VMWare product

Comment: I want to config my application in a virtual machine (my customer wants that) and I want a way to prevent him from copying my application to another system. I've no way to control some of my programs (only executable) so I want to set security on virtual machine.

Comment: Rather than making the VM hardware dependant, why not making the software hardware dependant? I've seen lots of license software (eg. everything that uses FlexLM) that use the hostid (which is usually the Physical MAC address) as the restriction - and if it is different - to require reactivation. Of course if it is a VM - you can change the MAC address to whatever you want, but you can combine the software restriction with reporting to your server (to detect concurrent instances of the software).